# Why is my Turkey's jaws out of alignment?

Tags: health, birds

So the new pet turkey that followed my wife home, seems to have a lower beak that's a little misaligned with the upper beak. She (the turkey) does not seem to be in pain, and is eating normally.The beak does close and open. Should I worry about this?

I'm adding a (poor quality) picture of the left side of the turkeys beak.  I kept says "pose!" but....  In the image you can see that the beak is just slightly open - the lower beak seems shifted to this side.

[image]

Comment: Been a while since I looked a turkey (or any bird) in the mouth but I don't see anything significant going on here.  As you are not seeing any issues with eating or health there may not be an issue.  BUT I am obligated to suggest that you might want to see a veterinarian.  Also this looks like it might be a wild turkey, depending on your local laws, it may be unlawful to keep it as domesticated.

Comment: @JamesJenkins - thanks for your input.  We're in a rural area near Seattle.  In compliance with law, but Turkeys are not normally found wild here.  I agree it has the look though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may have gotten that way because of a fight in the past. So long as it's not in pain and not hindering its eating, it should be okay.

My vet has a cat that roams around the office. One day a dog attacked it and bit its face. They did emergency surgery and the cat lived (thankfully) but they couldn't save the entire jaw. Half its jaw is missing. It's not in pain and eats wet food fine. The same thing may have happened to your turkey.